# call/run function from Kotlin with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, kotlin

I've wrote some lines of code in Kotlin now i want to execute this function from Javascrip or Nodejs is that possible? I only find solution for calling JS functions but not for calling Kotlin functions

for example:
JS:

```
function callKotlinHelloWorld(){
  //excute stuff
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun HelloWorld(){
  println("Hello World")
}
```

I heared from Kotlin/JS but there are some difrents from the normal JS and Kotlin

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html.

Edit:

> The Node.js target provided by Kotlin/JS enables you to create applications that run on a server or are executed on serverless infrastructure. This gives you all the advantages of executing in a JavaScript runtime, such as faster startup and a reduced memory footprint. With kotlinx-nodejs, you have typesafe access to the Node.js API directly from your Kotlin code.

[As per the corresponding section in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html#use-cases-for-kotlin-js)

Comment: is this compatible with Nodejs?

Comment: Yes it is, please see my edit.

Comment: I will try it Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer for others to find it in case it works :)